# Silent installer installshield to execute another setup file

Tags: installshield, silent-installer

How can we create a silent install package in installshield which can call another setup file after the installation is complete. In other words, the package will have another setup file and once main installer is finished, it should initiate child setup file.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about two (or more) Windows Installer-based installations? What version and edition of InstallShield do you have, as the Suite project is designed around this, but it can be impossible as described in a two .msi files case.

Comment: I have modified the project and included all files in a single setup file. I also included response file for silent installation but now I am not able to uninstall it from control panel. Not sure why.